# Function of the various Lexer commands in ANTLR4. Is my interpretation correct? What do each of them do?

Tags: command, antlr, antlr4, lexer, lexical-analysis

I have starting learning to write a lexer in ANTLR 4.5. From [this page](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md), which serves as documentation, I see that the following Lexer commands exist : more, pushMode(x), popMode, type(x), channel(x), mode(x), skip.

I have not been able to clearly understand their function. The following is my understanding of what each of them does:

## skip

This skips all the characters that have been read in the current token. The past tokens are left untouched.

So, if the lexer has read some character `a`, and it next reads `b`, corresponding to

```
SOME_RULE : 'b' -> skip;
```

then it will throw away both `a` and `b` and go to the next token.

## more

I am not sure what this does. The documentation says that the text that has been read will not be thrown away, but nothing about what tokens will finally be there. Suppose I have

```
RULE_1 : 'a' -> more;
RULE_2 : 'b';
```

If an `a` is read, and then a `b`, will the resulting token correspond to `RULE_2` with a semantic value `ab`, or `RULE_1 RULE_2`, or something else?

## type(x)

If I have

```
RULE_1 : 'a' -> type(TOKEN_1);
RULE_2 : 'b';
```

will only `a` be taken as the semantic value of `TOKEN_1`, or will all the characters corresponding to rules that were not tokens, right from the last token, be taken as the semantic value? If a `b` and an `a` arrive, will `TOKEN_1`s value be `a` or `ba`?

## mode(x)

This switches the mode to a new `mode`. But here, are the characters read till the point of switch kept or discarded? What about tokens? Does each mode have a separate stack?

## pushMode(x)

How is this different from `mode`? Is it the case that the already read characters are pushed to the mode it is going to, which doesn't happen in `mode`?

## popMode

What is popped out? If I have

```
RULE_1 : 'a' -> popMode;
RULE_2 : 'b' ;
```

If I get a `b` and an `a`, will `popMode` cause only `a` to be returned, or `ba`, or the tokens, if any? Why do I occasionally get an error due to an empty stack?

## channel(x)

I could not find an explanation for this. What is a channel?

Could anyone please clarify on the function of each of these commands, if possible with examples?

Please let me know if this is too broad.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

There is a free tutorial here [The ANTLR Mega Tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/).

Except `skip`, theese commands are very specialized and you can find when and why to use them, with examples, in [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference).

Comment: SO encourages answers to contain content that answers the question directly (not just links).